# Changed a user name in MySQL, but user is still able to login using previous user name

Tags: mysql, permissions

I created a user with user name **user_dev**. Then created a database **sampledb** and granted some privileges to this user on this database. Then I decided to edit username and changed it to **user_local**, and granted same privileges to this new name on same database.
Now both *user_dev* and *user_local* are able to login, but *user_dev* has no access to *sampledb* and privileges for *user_local* are correct.

```
SELECT `user` FROM `mysql`.`user`
```

does not show *user_dev*.
My question is, why *user_dev* is still able to login? Should I take any more steps to prevent this user from loging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- If you edited the privileges manually, you need to execute:

  ```
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```

  To reload the privileges cache on memory (needed to speedup the checks on every query).
- If you edited the privileges manually, you may have omitted an entry. Do not trust the `SHOW GRANTS FOR`, because it may omit the privileges edited directly on tables. Make sure that there are no `user_dev` not only on the user table, but on [all these](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant-table-structure.html).
- The fact that there is no `user_dev` user literally does not mean that a `user_dev` user cannot login. I will explain myself. The user that you submit is compared against the user privileges tables, so user_dev (let's say that is on localhost) matches:

  ```
  'user_dev'@'localhost'
  'user%'@'127.0.0.1'
  ''@'%'
  '%'@'localhost'
  ```

  In fact, by default, anonymous users from localhost can login, and all users can read and write on the test database. Run [mysql_secure_installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, actually user_dev is logged in as an anonymous user. I didn't know about anonymous login, thanks.